# How to set up an organization for a single user and upgrade to Standard Support

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and accidentally created a project without an organization. I want to upgrade to Standard Support to direct my technical questions appropriately, but cannot find a way to fix my organization. I have searched through all the support documentation but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. At this point, I would like to start over from scratch to better align with the YouTube videos that I am following. Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My recommendation is to create a Google Workspace account. Then link your Google Cloud account and Workspace together, which will create an organization. You will need a domain name that you own. Another alternative is to replace Google Workspace with Google Cloud Identity. The former is better in my opinion because of its features, security, and management options. A one-user Workspace account is inexpensive.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance.  I have a Google Workspace Individual plan that I'm ready to activate once I understand what exactly I need it for.  I am researching all of this, but can you tell me how to link my Google Cloud account and Workspace Individual together?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization